# Python: How to pass an object into another class's parameter?

Tags: python, class

I am new to Python. And I was trying to make a class that uses another object's functions within it but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!

So this is a rough example of what i want to do

```js
class Dog:
 def bark(self):
  print("Hello")

class DogHouse:
 def __init__(self, dog):
  self.owner = dog

 def bark2(self):
  ???
```

So I want to be able to call the dog's bark within DogHouse, but I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

Comment: Paste us your code (format with Ctrl-K), identify the specific problem and then we can critique it.

Comment: *"I was trying to make a class that uses another object's functions within it"* You mean class B uses A's methods, but B is not a subclass of A? It's ok for methods in B to call methods on instances of A, but only one call level deep... don't violate the Law of Demeter *("at most one dot in an object reference")*

Comment: ...or else if you want both classes A and B to share some methods, then have them both inherit from a common base class C. You can force the method to be abstract/ not have a default implementation by having it `raise Exception`. It's hard to know what you really want without seeing specifics and code.

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://pastebin.com/RPbRrWVN)? (Just a random pastebin I found from a different question…) This is one way an `Eggs` object can use a `Spam` object's methods, but there are many others. Maybe if you can explain why that _isn't_ what you want, that will help you explain what you actually _do_ what.

Comment: Look, if you don't add some specifics quick, this will soon be closed-unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Try `self.owner.bark()` ... and then go through some tutorials! This is a really basic question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

What you're talking about is [object oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).  I would recommend you take a course on the topic either at a university or [online](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud036).  However I've taken the time to whip a quick example to do what I think you want it to do:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello world")

    def new_print(self, some_word):
        print(some_word.swapcase())

    @staticmethod
    def newer_print(some_word):
        print(some_word.lower())


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("world")

        #create the object of Class A and then call the method
        temp = A()
        temp.new_print("This is a test")

        #call the static method of Class A
        A.newer_print("Just one more test")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    #create the object for Class B
    test = B()
```

Notice that `Class A` has two methods (besides `__init__`).  The first (`new_print`) requires an object of that class be instantiated before calling the method.  The second (`newer_print`) can be run statically.

Calling another classes method is simply done either:

1. creating an object of the class and calling it's methods or,
2. Calling the static methods of the class

If you look at B's instantiation method you'll see that these two cases are demonstrated.

Comment: What is the purpose of having object as an argument of the class? I am under the impression that the arg is passed to the class since it is not defined via __init__ yet it isn't called anywhere.

Comment: @mikey if you're talking about `class A(object):` then that is Python 2 specific syntax that inherits the new class objects.  This is the default behavior in Python 3.